# Laravel 5.4 Class Imagick not found, while it is installed

Tags: php, laravel, imagick

PHP has all imagick libs, but in Laravel 5.4 it said class not found.

Code:

```
$img = new Imagick($full_name);
```

This if(extension_loaded('imagick')) returns true.
So it's installed.

phpinfo() output:
[image: phpinfo() output:]

Any help why Laravel treat PHP class as it's own?

ERROR for $img = new \Imagick($full_name):
FatalErrorException
Class 'Imagick' not found

ERROR for $img = new Imagick($full_name) :
FatalErrorException
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Imagick' not found

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Read the error closely - it probably says something like `App\Controllers\Http\Imagick` can't be found - then read up on [PHP namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: Thats probably because Imagick() is not fully qualified name within your Namespace. Try $img = new \Imagick($full_name);

Comment: @ceejayoz not sure where you pointing...

Comment: @theguy You need to understand how namespacing works in PHP. Laravel uses it extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to look at the default namespace for imagick, so you have to write it like this, and it will find imagick class in a proper way:

```
$img = new \Imagick($full_name);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted since it worked for me.